# Grafana 100% stacked bar chart

Tags: plot, grafana

How would I achieve this graph?

[image]

this is the query i am using
select Region, column1, column2 from table

and the data it returns
[image]

is this possible in Grafana? since this is not a time series, i’m not sure… but i wanted to ask anyway, maybe someone knows something…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bar Chart panel](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/bar-chart/) is a first choice for non time series data visualization in the Grafana. Use `Orientation: Horizontal` and `Stacking: 100%` + some minor configs may be needed to achieve desired result precisely.

Comment: Where do I find Stacking: 100% in the Bar Chart options? I am using Grafana v8.0.5 and I don't seem to find the stacking option anywhere.

Comment: @Sederfo use the latest Grafana version. It may not be available in older version. E.g. 8.1.4 has that - https://play.grafana.org/d/ktMs4D6Mk/5-bar-charts-and-pie-charts?orgId=1&editPanel=15

Comment: Do you know what kind of query this panel needs? I always get *Bar charts requires a string field*.

Comment: @dur You can see some data sample in Data inspect of https://play.grafana.org/d/ktMs4D6Mk/5-bar-charts-and-pie-charts?orgId=1&editPanel=15&inspect=15&inspectTab=query A typical query would use the Table data type.

Comment: @pba Thanks. This example uses a CSV file. That's nothing I could use.

Comment: @dur The actual query depends on your datasource, but for example I am using postgres and knowing which data the SQL query should return from this sample was very useful.